# Analyzing the alliteration of the first line of Lolita

Tags: literary-device, vladimir-nabokov, lolita

> Lolita, light of my life, fire of my loins. My sin, my soul.

Please help me analyze the alliteration from the line above. Which 'L' words attribute to the alliteration? Lo, Li from Lolita and light, life, loins? Or just light, life, loins.

Comment: There are no rules that tell you exactly which words contribute to alliteration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is alliteration adjacent words and/or close together words starting with the same letter? If words between are permitted then how many?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/4710/is-alliteration-adjacent-words-and-or-close-together-words-starting-with-the-sam)

Answer (score 4):

In poetry, alliteration requires stressed syllables that begin with the same consonant sound. Nabokov's novel *Lolita* is written in prose, so we don't need to analyse the metre to determine which syllables are stressed; we only need to know each word's main stress.

In Nabokov's first two sentences, we can find two groups of alliterations:

1. based on the "l" sound: "Lo**l**ita, **l**ight of my **l**ife, fire of my **l**oins"
2. based on the "s" sound: "My **s**in, my **s**oul."

There are two other sound patterns that strengthen these strings of alliterations:

1. the [assonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assonance) of the "i" sound in "l**i**ght", "l**i**fe" and "f**i**re",
2. the assonance between "L**o**lita" and "l**oi**ns" (obviously with some liberty, since "o" and "oi" are not exactly the same sounds),
3. the repetition of "my", which on the one hand exhibits assonance with "light", "life" and "fire", and on the other hand provides a bridge between the first group of alliterations ("my life", "my loins") and the second group "My sin, my soul").

One can see that Nabokov does not only use alliteration in these opening sentences but reinforces this sound effect by means of other sound effects. The next sentence continues the alliterations, this time based on the letter "t":

> Lo-lee-ta: the **t**ip of the **t**ongue **t**aking a **t**rip of three steps down the palate **t**o **t**ap, at three, on the **t**eeth.

For Humbert Humbert, speaking the girl's name is a sensual experience. He can't resist the sound effects, just like he can't resist the girl.

Comment: But the stressed syllable of Lolita falls on the second syllable, loLIta. So that it's much be "Li", "light", "life", "loins". At the same time, alliteration can be count on the first syllable even though it's not stressed. That's mean it can be "Lo", "light", "life", "loins" or "Li", "light", "life", "loins" , or "Lo", "Li", "light", "life", "loins". Which is right? I'm really confused.

Comment: @mm Where did you find the claim that alliteration relies on the first syllable? Does that apply to unstressed first syllables?

Comment: https://www.litcharts.com/literary-devices-and-terms/alliteration#:~:text=Alliteration%20is%20a%20figure%20of,stressed%20syllables%20of%20those%20words.